# Is there a way to diagnose Male Pattern Baldness?

Tags: hairloss, supplement, diagnosis

I'm thinking about supplementing in Creatine Monohydrate because of its various benefits on weight lifting and it also being really affordable. In different studies I read about Creatine intake leading to hair loss, because it raises the testosterone to dihydrotestosterone ratio. However, as the studies show, this only affects males that are already affected by some sort of male pattern baldness (eg. inherited).

Is there a way to diagnose male pattern baldness? It is suggested to look at your relatives (especially on your fathers side of the family, because apperently this ins inherited on the y-chromosome) and search for baldness. For me thats not an option, I've never met my father or other relatives from that side of the "family"...

**Source:**
Van der Merwe, J., Brooks, N. E., & Myburgh, K. H. (2009). Three weeks of creatine monohydrate supplementation affects dihydrotestosterone to testosterone ratio in college-aged rugby players. *Clinical Journal of Sport Medicine*, 19(5), 399-404. doi: [10.1097/JSM.0b013e3181b8b52f](https://doi.org/10.1097/JSM.0b013e3181b8b52f)

Also available from NCBI: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19741313

Comment: If it’s hereditary, you’d think your doc would be able to do a DNA test, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the following articles which may be of help.

> **[Hillmer, et al. (2005)](https://doi.org/10.1086/431425)**
>
> Androgenetic alopecia (AGA), or male-pattern baldness, is the most common form of hair loss. Its pathogenesis is androgen dependent, and genetic predisposition is the major requirement for the phenotype. We demonstrate that genetic variability in the androgen receptor gene (*AR*) is the cardinal prerequisite for the development of early-onset AGA, with an etiological fraction of 0.46. The investigation of a large number of genetic variants covering the *AR* locus suggests that a polyglycine-encoding GGN repeat in exon 1 is a plausible candidate for conferring the functional effect. The X-chromosomal location of *AR* stresses the importance of the maternal line in the inheritance of AGA.

This article was cited in an article by **[Ceruti, et al. (2018)](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.mce.2017.09.009)**

> Beyond sexual functions, androgens exert their action in skin physiology and pathophysiology. Skin cells are able to synthesize most active androgens from gonadal or adrenal precursors and the enzymes involved in skin steroidogenesis are implicated both in normal or pathological processes. Even when the role of androgens and androgen receptor (AR) in skin pathologies has been studied for decades, their molecular mechanisms in skin disorders remain largely unknown. Here, we analyze recent studies of androgens and AR roles in several skin-related disorders, focusing in the current understanding of their molecular mechanisms in androgenetic alopecia (AGA). We review the molecular pathophysiology of type 2 5α-reductase, AR coactivators, the paracrine factors deregulated in dermal papillae (such as TGF-β, IGF 1, WNTs and DKK-1) and the crosstalk between AR and Wnt signaling in order to shed some light on new promising treatments.

and **[Adil & Godwin (2017)](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jaad.2017.02.054)**

> Androgenetic alopecia, or male pattern hair loss, is a hair loss disorder mediated by dihydrotestosterone, the potent form of testosterone. Currently, minoxidil and finasteride are Food and Drug Administration (FDA)–approved, and HairMax LaserComb, which is FDA-cleared, are the only treatments recognized by the FDA as treatments of androgenetic alopecia.
>
> **Objective**
>
> This systematic review and meta-analysis assesses the efficacy of nonsurgical treatments of androgenetic alopecia in comparison to placebo for improving hair density, thickness, growth (defined by an increased anagen:telogen ratio), or subjective global assessments done by patients and investigators.

### References

Adil, A., & Godwin, M. (2017). The effectiveness of treatments for androgenetic alopecia: a systematic review and meta-analysis. *Journal of the American Academy of Dermatology*, 77(1), 136-141. [10.1016/j.jaad.2017.02.054](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jaad.2017.02.054)

Ceruti, J. M., Leirós, G. J., & Balañá, M. E. (2018). Androgens and androgen receptor action in skin and hair follicles. *Molecular and cellular endocrinology*, 465, 122-133. doi: [10.1016/j.mce.2017.09.009](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.mce.2017.09.009)

Hillmer, A. M., Hanneken, S., Ritzmann, S., Becker, T., Freudenberg, J., Brockschmidt, F. F., ... & Heyn, U. (2005). Genetic variation in the human androgen receptor gene is the major determinant of common early-onset androgenetic alopecia. *The American Journal of Human Genetics*, 77(1), 140-148. doi: [10.1086/431425](https://doi.org/10.1086/431425)